# Running SoapUi through Maven is not loading the datasource

Tags: maven, soapui

SoapUI 4.5.1 plugin with Maven

I've got a functioning test that loads the datasource correctly and I am then able to access the loaded data in a subsequent Groovy script step.

```
log.info context.expand( '${DataSource#req_messageID}' )
```

However, when running the same testCase via the Maven plugin the datasource is not loaded.  I have verified that the path to the xls file for loading is passed into the maven run, and accurate.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and eventually realised you need the maven-soapui-**pro**-plugin for the datasources to work, as this is a pro feature